# How to solve Facebook conversations API issue?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Can anyone help me for Conversations API?

I am getting following error :

> (#12) This endpoint is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher
>
> FB.api('/470645953121535/conversations'

Comment: it should not be deprecated, file a bug